# Uniqueness of weak limit in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{x_n\}$ a sequence in $H$ and $y,z\in H$.

Suppose that $x_n\rightarrow y$ and $x_n \rightarrow z$ weakly.

Now let $\varepsilon > 0$, and $w\in H$. Then there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n > N$, $$|\langle x_n, w\rangle - \langle y, w\rangle|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$ and $$|\langle x_n, w\rangle - \langle z, w\rangle|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

So take $n > N$. Then we have $$|\langle y-z, w\rangle| = |\langle y - x_n + x_n - z, w\rangle| \leq |\langle y - x_n,w\rangle| + |\langle x_n - z, w\rangle| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

So since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary we may conclude that $\langle y-z, w\rangle = 0$. But then since $w$ was arbitrary, we may conclude that $y=z$. Therefore weak limits are unique.

Does this proof work?

Comment: Yes this works.

Comment: You may have noticed that you replicated much of the proof of the "uniqueness of real limits" statement. You can basically skip the first half the proof by citing this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler version: 
$$\begin{split}
\|x-z\|^2 &= \langle x-z, x-z\rangle =\langle x,x-z\rangle - \langle z,x-z\rangle\\&=
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n, x-z\rangle-
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n, x-z\rangle = \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n-x_n,x-z\rangle =0.
\end{split}
$$
(the main idea is to use the test element $w:=x-z$)

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way.